# jQuery animate on hover, instantly disappear on mouseout?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following code on my website, which causes a div to slide out from the left. This works fine, but when the mouse leaves the area I want to the div to instantly disappear, instead of animating back left again. I have tried many different ways of doing this but none seem to work. I'm sure there is an easy way of doing this. Thanks :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#side-nav a").hover(function(){
        $text = $(this).html();
        $text = "#" + $text + "-box";
        $($text).animate({width:'toggle'},450);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes a second method for the [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) portion (woth one function, it runs on both `mouseenter` *and* `mouseleave`, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#side-nav a").hover(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).html() + "-box").animate({width:'toggle'},450);
  }, function() {
    $("#" + $(this).html() + "-box").animate({width:'toggle'},0);
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JczqU/), this allows you to still use `toggle`, but an 0 duration triggers an instant css change, rather than an animation.  I would consider though, instead of using the HTML, use the anchors link, like this:

```
<a href="#MyDiv">
```

Then your code is much simpler, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#side-nav a").hover(function(){
    $(this.hash).animate({width:'toggle'},450);
  }, function() {
    $(this.hash).animate({width:'toggle'},0);
  });
});
```

You're using the `href="#id"` as an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) directly, and if you're also hiding the other element it's pointing at via JavaScript, it means users without JS are much better supported, this will degrade gracefully without hiding content.